# Proper format for setting the variable to the output of a command

Tags: bash, azure, azure-cli, azure-cli2

If I run this command from the Azure CLI, I get a true false depending on if the resource group actually exists.  Works great.

```
az group exists –n MyResourceGroup
```

It also works in this form:

```
az group exists –n MyResourceGroup
```

If, in a bash script I try to set a variable to the output of those commands:

```
GROUPEXISTS1="$(az group exists --name MyResourceGroup)"
GROUPEXISTS2="$(az group exists –n MyResourceGroup)"
```

Only the first one works.  When I use -n I get the following error:

> az: error: unrecognized arguments: –n MyResourceGroup

However I know that command works with the -n parameter.  Do I need to encode a single dash when using it inside "$()"?  Why else would it not accept that form?

Comment: Do you use products from Microsoft to write bash scripts? `–` != `-`

Answer (score 2):

Looks like your editor replaces hyphen-minus `-` (U+002D) with dash `–`. These are different chars. Bash and other unix-like shells treat dash as common char, not a start of option.
If you have a lot of already written script files and don't know if there some dashes instead of minus, you can convert them automatically with command like

```
sed -i 's/–/-/g' your-script-file
```

Answer (score 0):

You could check your script carefully. `–n` is different from `–n`. In Azure Cloud Shell, you can clearly see the difference.

[image]

Modify your script as below:

```
GROUPEXISTS2="$(az group exists -n MyResourceGroup)"
```